# should every TCP data packet be acknowledge or not?

Tags: networking, tcp

If a tcp program A send two data packets to another TCP program B, packet 1: sequence number from 1000 to 2000; packet 2: seq number from 2000 to 3000.

Generally B should reply with 2 ACKs, one for acknowledging packet 1 and the other for packet 2.
Now, if only the second ACK is received by A, will A still wait for the first ACK or not?

I know TCP is byte-oriented stream protocl. so A should not wait for the first ACK, is it right? In theory, it is like this, how about the real implemented TCP stack?

BTW, I have a pecular question. If A send to B an ACK to with ack seq number 3001(this is for acknowledging packet 2). But someone in the middle modify the ack seq number to 2501, that's being said, B acknowledge a half TCP packet. 
Then will A retransmit from byte which corresponds to seq 2000 or 2501?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, TCP applies a "sliding window" mechanism to reduce the number of acknowledgments needed.

A nice visualization and explanation: http://histrory.visualland.net/tcp_swnd.html

Comment: This is theory, how about the practical, I mean the TCP stack implementation. And I have a pecular question, pls check my updated question. thanks!

Comment: @misteryes This is also real-world behavior. If you want to see the "practical behavior", install a monitor like Wireshark or consult one of the open-source TCP stacks (e.g. Linux).

Answer (score 6):

TCP will ack sequence numbers, not packets.  So even without "someone in the middle", Program A can ack just a fraction of a received packet (i.e. socket doesn't have enough buffer space for all of the packet.)  In your example, 2501 will then be re-transmitted by Program B.

TCP also supports Selective Ack, so that just a missing segment (in the seq number space) needs to be transmitted

Comment: +1 This answer is wonderful. Right on the spot with the most important scentence at the beginning.  I wonder why it has (had) no upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

**B** offers a 'window' (of buffer space) to **A** in its acknowledgement. **A** need not wait for a specific acknowledgement before send subsequent packets so long as it doesn't exceed **B**'s current window.

Caveat: Much simplified, both in the interest of brevity and due my somewhat limited understanding of the protocol. [RFC: 813 - WINDOW AND ACKNOWLEDGEMENT STRATEGY IN TCP](http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc813/?include_text=1) talks about this very technique.